# Pandas DataFrame doesn't have the entire data and uses three dots instead

Tags: python, pandas, file, dataframe, encoding

Got this .txt file

```
 Dia  Precio marginal en el sistema español (EUR/MWh)  Precio marginal en el sistema portugués (EUR/MWh)  Energía total de compra sistema español (MWh)  Energía total de venta sistema español (MWh)  Energía total de compra sistema portugués (MWh)  Energía total de venta sistema portugués (MWh)  Energía total del mercado Ibérico (MWh)  Energía total con bilaterales del mercado Ibér...  Importación de España desde Portugal (MWh)  Exportación de España a Portugal (MWh)
   1                                             9.57                                               9.57                                        21440.2                                       21044.6                                             2214                                          2609.6                                  23654.2                                            29281.5                                       395.6                                       0
   2                                                0                                                  0                                        21568.7                                       20602.7                                             1304                                            2270                                  22872.7                                            28254.7                                         966                                       0
   3                                                0                                                  0                                        21727.9                                       20306.8                                           1030.5                                          2451.6                                  22758.4                                            27934.1                                      1421.1                                       0
   4                                                0                                                  0                                        21703.8                                       20103.8                                           1119.4                                          2719.4                                  22823.2                                            27603.4                                        1600                                       0
   5                                                0                                                  0                                        21050.3                                       19450.3                                           1113.9                                          2713.9                                  22164.2                                            26645.1                                        1600                                       0
   6                                                0                                                  0                                        20830.5                                       19230.5                                           1114.8                                          2714.8                                  21945.3                                            26364.9                                        1600                                       0
   7                                                0                                                  0                                        20725.9                                       19125.9                                           1124.2                                          2724.2                                  21850.1                                            26364.8                                        1600                                       0
   8                                                0                                                  0                                        20790.8                                       19190.8                                           1145.5                                          2745.5                                  21936.3                                              26827                                        1600                                       0
   9                                                0                                                  0                                        21348.5                                       19748.5                                             1162                                            2762                                  22510.5                                              27289                                        1600                                       0
  10                                                0                                                  0                                        21813.3                                       20213.3                                           1183.1                                          2783.1                                  22996.4                                            28189.4                                        1600                                       0
  11                                                0                                                  0                                        22175.3                                       20575.3                                           1215.1                                          2815.1                                  23390.4                                              29058                                        1600                                       0
  12                                                0                                                  0                                        22653.6                                       21053.6                                           1205.9                                          2805.9                                  23859.5                                              29630                                        1600                                       0
  13                                                0                                                  0                                        22637.9                                       21286.4                                           1282.5                                            2634                                  23920.4                                            29812.3                                      1351.5                                       0
  14                                                0                                                  0                                        22686.5                                       21622.1                                           1569.6                                            2634                                  24256.1                                            29999.5                                      1064.4                                       0
  15                                                0                                                  0                                          23045                                       22153.7                                           1742.7                                            2634                                  24787.7                                            30471.6                                       891.3                                       0
  16                                                0                                                  0                                        22678.6                                       21986.4                                           1941.8                                            2634                                  24620.4                                            30206.7                                       692.2                                       0
  17                                                0                                                  0                                        22046.9                                       21575.7                                           2162.8                                            2634                                  24209.7                                            29765.1                                       471.2                                       0
  18                                                0                                                  0                                        20583.8                                       20486.5                                           2536.7                                            2634                                  23120.5                                            28778.4                                        97.3                                       0
  19                                               10                                                 10                                        20436.8                                       21197.9                                           3490.1                                            2729                                  23926.9                                            30031.2                                           0                                   761.1
  20                                               15                                              25.31                                        20328.1                                       21428.1                                           4211.7                                          3111.7                                  24539.8                                            30849.8                                           0                                    1100
  21                                            27.32                                              27.32                                          20709                                       21808.9                                           4334.4                                          3234.5                                  25043.4                                            31449.9                                           0                                  1099.9
  22                                               30                                                 30                                        21466.4                                       22448.9                                           4223.5                                            3241                                  25689.9                                            32160.6                                           0                                   982.5
  23                                             30.8                                               30.8                                        21651.9                                       22371.4                                           3980.5                                            3261                                  25632.4                                            31784.1                                           0                                   719.5
  24                                             29.1                                               29.1                                        20191.1                                       20725.1                                             3775                                            3241                                  23966.1                                            29685.7                                           0                                     534
```

While creating a Pandas DataFrame from it, I was getting

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position
>   40: invalid continuation byte

In order to solve that problem, had to specify the encoding to latin-1.

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\file_location\file_name.txt', encoding='latin-1')
```

Then, when printing df,

```
    Dia  Precio marginal en el sistema español (EUR/MWh)  Precio marginal en el sistema portugués (EUR/MWh)  Energía total de compra sistema español (MWh)  Energía total de venta sistema español (MWh)  Energía total de compra sistema portugués (MWh)  Energía total de venta sistema portugués (MWh)  Energía total del mercado Ibérico (MWh)  Energía total con bilaterales del mercado Ibér...  Importación de España desde Portugal (MWh)  Exportación de España a Portugal (MWh)
0      1                                          ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
1      2                                          ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
2      3                                          ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
3      4                                          ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
4      5                                          ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
5      6                                          ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
6      7                                          ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
7      8                                          ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
8      9                                          ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
9     10                                          ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
10    11                                          ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
11    12                                          ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
12    13                                          ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
13    14                                          ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
14    15                                          ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
15    16                                          ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
16    17                                          ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
17    18                                          ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
18    19                                          ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
19    20                                          ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
20    21                                          ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
21    22                                          ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
22    23                                          ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
23    24                                          ...
```

The problem with this print result is that instead of showing the values for all the columns (like the file has), it appears the three dots - **...**.

I tried changing the file to .csv instead of .txt, removing the header, using read_table and writing to a file but kept receiving the same result.

Comment: can you provide your CSV file here or at least first five data of your file

Comment: just added to the question @Darkknight

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a lot of columns so your data might be truncated

You can try

`pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None) pd.set_option('display.width', None) pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)`

to eliminate any kind of column truncation

Comment: I believe it should be `pd.set_option("display.max_colwidth", None)` now since passing a negative integer is deprecated in new versions

Answer (score 3):

Note:

Passing a negative integer is deprecated in version 1.0 and will not be supported in future version. Instead, use "None" to not limit the column width.

```
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
import pandas as pd   
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\file_location\file_name.txt', encoding='latin-1')
print(df.to_string())
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.